# A way to use images for 3D mockups using javascript

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im trying to experiment with product design using javascript, in which the user can select a shirt, mug, box, book for example, and insert a text and/or an image and move it or rotate it or scale it, then they can apply the changes, and a 3D mockup will be generated.

Is this possible using a Javascript library such as Three.js and/or jQuery, or will i need to actually use another technology other than JS, for example WebGL directly ?

I have not dabbled with javascript before as im usually a backend PHP developer, but this idea has caught my attention and i couldnt find enough resources online about it.

Comment: Treee.js should work fine. Not sure what is 3d mockup, like "screenshot"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this should definitely be doable with three.js

Worst case you can just manipulate a plane with a texture around the product, however I suspect a better way would be manipulating a texture. This would be quite easy if you don't want to manipulate the image in real-time on the 3d mockup, but likely also simple enough to do in real-time.